# Configuration settings for Jenkins Git Plugin?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

The Jenkins Git Plugin asks requires us to set the `user.name` and `user.email` value. Should we set it to the normal config values (for personal projects) or something specific to Jenkins...?

Answer (score 1):

Normally this will only be used if Jenkins commits changes to the repository (tags or automatically committing build artifacts).  I would suggest making a Jenkins specific user so you can differentiate any automatic commits from those made by a real person, but there is nothing requiring it.

Comment: Thanks you. I would have upvoted if my reputation was more than 15 :) .

Comment: This can also happen if your Git repo is protected and requires authentication even for cloning.  But JSON is right: you should have a build-system-specific username.

Comment: Credentials are separate from user.name and  user.email configuration.